# Ruby Nested Hash values_at not working

Tags: ruby, hash

I am using a nested hash in Ruby, but the `values_at` method is not returning any data, and I cannot find out why.

```
j =  {"grandpa" => { "dad" => {"child 1" => {}, "child 2" => {} }, "uncle" => {"child 3" => {}, "child 4" => {} } } }
puts j.values_at("dad")
```

It does not print anything.  I believe `"child1"` and `"child2"` should be printed, as they are both values of `"dad"`.

If I run `values_at` for `"grandpa"` I receive the correct response of:

```
{"dad" => {"child 1" => {}, "child2" => {}}, "uncle" => {"child 3" => {}, "child 4" => {}}}
```

What am I missing about the format? Or do I just not understand nested hashes?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Hash#values_at documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Hash/values_at)

> Return an array containing the values associated with the given keys

The method doesn't know how to handle nested hashes. You'll need to navigate down to the hash level you want to search.  For example:

`j["grandpa"].values_at("dad")`